# Get only the ellipsis text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ellipsis

Nice code, just wondered if it is possible to query and get the ellipsis text (i.e. with the dots in and not the original text)?

If I add the text

> This is a long sentence

and (using the relevant css for ellipsis) it gets shortened to

> This is a long sen ...

Is there a way to get the text

```
"This is a long sen ..."
```

from the `$("p")` DOM object rather than the original text?

Comment: Do you mean when using [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)? No, CSS adds those as needed; they're not actually part of the DOM, and therefore cannot be computed using JavaScript.

Comment: What is the "nice code" you're referring to?

Comment: I think @Blazemonger is probably right, but why do you need it anyway? Perhaps there is a way around your requirement.

Comment: yes, using for example "text-overflow: ellipsis" in the css, just wondering if other ellipsis libraries such as dotdotdot can achieve this

Comment: I want to make a pdf (jsPDF) from my html and if css has already done a nice job of shortening the text to suit the available space then I would like to get the shortened text. Since its a pdf of fixed size I probably mostly can use full sized text, but maybe sometimes the text wont fit and then in the pdf it will also not fit the container space

Comment: Even if this is getting old, the question has been answered [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45237520/2592358) . And it **WORKS FOR EVERY BROWSER**

Comment: Proto - This does not work, the text copied to the new element is the same full length text and not the ellipse shortened version https://jsfiddle.net/orecgujz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [have a **rough draft**](http://jsfiddle.net/axHs8/3/) that **needs some browser-specific tweaking**.

JavaScript:

```
jQuery.fn.getShowingText = function () {
    // Add temporary element for measuring character widths
    $('body').append('<div id="Test" style="padding:0;border:0;height:auto;width:auto;position:absolute;display:none;"></div>');
    var longString = $(this).text();
    var eleWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
    var totalWidth = 0;
    var totalString = '';
    var finished = false;
    var ellipWidth = $('#Test').html('&hellip;').innerWidth();
    var offset = 7; // seems to differ based on browser (6 for Chrome and 7 for Firefox?)
    for (var i = 0;
    (i < longString.length) && ((totalWidth) < (eleWidth-offset)); i++) {
        $('#Test').text(longString.charAt(i));
        totalWidth += $('#Test').innerWidth();
        totalString += longString.charAt(i);
        if(i+1 === longString.length)
        {
            finished = true;
        }
    }
    $('body').remove('#Test'); // Clean up temporary element
    if(finished === false)
    {
        return totalString.substring(0,totalString.length-3)+"…";
    }
    else
    {
        return longString;
    }
}
console.log($('#ellDiv').getShowingText());
```

CSS:

```
#Test {
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position:absolute;
    white-space: pre;
}
div {
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    padding:0;
}
```

With the caveat that the `offset` needs to change depending on the browser, unless someone can figure out what is causing it.

I suspect `letter-spacing` or similar?

Comment: Nope http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/axHs8/2/. All I did was add spaces to the word in the div.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```js
function getEllipsis(command, characters) {
 for (var i = command.length; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (command.substring(0, i).length < characters) {
   if (i < command.length) {
    command = command.substring(0, i) + "...";
   }
   return command;
  }
 }
}
console.log(getEllipsis("I am a long sentence",16))
console.log(getEllipsis("But I am even longer",20))
```