# How to take result text when text-overflow property is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with css property `text-overflow : ellipsis` to add ellipsis and show the text in a single line.

When I perform jquery `.text()` or `.html()`, I get the full string, but I need the exact text displaying in the div currently (not the full string).

Can some one guide me how to take the exact displaying string using jquery or JS?

Actual String = `"abcdefghijklmnop"`
Due to CSS, the div displays `"abcd..."`

My expected result (using jQuery or JS) `"abcd..."`

Comment: CSS is just applying styles here, not manipulating the string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get only the ellipsis text using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095222/get-only-the-ellipsis-text-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without trying to mimic CSS and recreate the strings with the ellipsis using JS.

The reason for this is that CSS only manipulates what is displayed to the user, not the HTML source itself. You can verify this by checking the source code for your document. This means that when you use `.text()` or `.html()` you get the values from the DOM, rather than what is displayed via the CSS filter.

There are a couple of hacks that does a pretty good job, but it is still no guarantee that the JS correctly mimics how CSS renders the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of values you need every time then you can just use `JS` Like for example if it was always 4 values that gets entered in than it would be like this,

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkrwu6r2/)

form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>
    <label for="txt">My txt: </albel>
        <input type="text" id="myTxt"><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Send">
    </P>
 </form>
```

js

```
document.getElementById('submitButton').onclick = function() {

    myVariable = document.getElementById("myTxt").value;
    alert(myVariable.slice(0, 4));
};
```

No matter what is typed in to the textbox it will be sliced to the first 4 characters.