# How to apply displayed text from one element to other using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Applied content `overflow: hidden` style using `css` and rendered text to `span` element using `jQuery`. Rendered text is displaying actual text which I don't want to see. Below is the code how i tried:

i want to display same text as `#user-name-display` in `#top-bar-user-name-display` element.

> how to implement it using simple script?

HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#top-bar-user-name-display').html($('#users-name-display').html());
});
```

```css
#users-name-display {
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="users-name-display">Alexander Pierce sdfsdf sd fsd fsdf sdf sd</p>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="hidden-xs"><span id="top-bar-user-name-display"><!-- Name will be displayed from #users-name-display --></span></span>
</a>
```

**Current O/P:**

Alexander Pierce sd...

Alexander Pierce sdfsdf sd fsd fsdf sdf sd

**Expected O/P:**

Alexander Pierce sd...

Alexander Pierce sd...

Comment: Show the relevant code in the question. We shouldn't have to go off site just to review your issue. Also not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish or what your specific problem is trying to achieve it. Take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Look into my answer that is like you want

Comment: I believe the best way to do this would be to copy the element `CSS` to `#top-bar-user-name-display`.

Comment: @charlietfl edited

Comment: @Proto it's not working because in my actual code the span I mentioned in code available inside ul > li > a > [actual span is here] so the CSS style is  overriding by other styles

Comment: Still not clear why you can't use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. You haven't provided any css for `#top-bar-user-name-display` for anyone to help see the issue -- or -- you haven't explained problem clearly enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#users-name-display`  display `Alexander Pierce...` only because you had set the div frame `width` to 150px. So whole text can't be displayed, in the second you had the whole text because you haven't limit the div width.

You must just change the `#top-bar-user-name-display` width to 150 in your css.

Try this code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#top-bar-user-name-display').html($('#users-name-display').html());
$('#top-bar-user-name-display').css("display","block");
});
```

```css
#users-name-display, #top-bar-user-name-display {
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#top-bar-user-name-display{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="users-name-display">Alexander Pierce sdfsdf sd fsd fsdf sdf sd</p>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="hidden-xs"><span id="top-bar-user-name-display"><!-- Name will be displayed from #users-name-display --></span></span>
</a>
```

Comment: your code worked perfect i just changed to `$('#top-bar-user-name-display').css("display","inline-block");` and its done....

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#top-bar-user-name-display').html($('#users-name-display').html());
});
```

```css
.users-name-display{
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="users-name-display" class="users-name-display">Alexander Pierce sdfsdf sd fsd fsdf sdf sd</p>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="hidden-xs"><span id="top-bar-user-name-display" class="users-name-display"><!-- Name will be displayed from #users-name-display --></span></span>
</a>
```

I have added a class as *users-name-display*

and Display Block

Comment: Updated Now check

Comment: Thanks for helping but still not getting what i expecting

Comment: According to your question, this is **EXACTLY** what you wanted

Comment: @SourabhSomani Unfortunately your snippet example is working. but when i apply to my actual code its not.. Thank you for helping. Your is the simplest.

Comment: Its Okay :) I think same thing he is doing using javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

Change id users-name-display to class users-name-display

Give same classname to both p tag and span

Or

use below jquery code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var showChar = 100;
 var ellipsestext = "...";
 $('.more').each(function() {
  var content = $(this).html();

  if(content.length > showChar) {

   var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
   var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

   var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>';
      $('#top-bar-user-name-display').html(html);
   $(this).html(html);
  }

 });
});
```

```css
a {
 color: #0254EB
}
a:visited {
 color: #0254EB
}
a.morelink {
 text-decoration:none;
 outline: none;
}
.morecontent span {
 display: none;
}
.comment {
 width: 400px;
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment more">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
 Vestibulum laoreet, nunc eget laoreet sagittis,
 quam ligula sodales orci, congue imperdiet eros tortor ac lectus.
 Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
 blandit id luctus felis convallis.
 Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
 Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.
</div>
<span id="top-bar-user-name-display"><!-- Name will be displayed from #users-name-display --></span>
```

Comment: @Syed Nizamudeen check it. If any doubt. Let me know.