# HTML, JS, get only displayed value of the element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some `div`s in my code and I have applied `text-overflow: ellipsis` to them.

Let's say the first div has value of: "Hello I am a div element" and since there is `text-overflow` being applied the displayed value is: "Hello I am...".

I want to know if there is a way to get the displayed value instead of full value ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get clamped (with ellipsis) textContent from textNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936263/get-clamped-with-ellipsis-textcontent-from-textnode)

Comment: Sorry I read your question wrong, though you want to get the full value.

Comment: Try to see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45237520/9300219) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case, the easiest may be to set your title attribute as well, so on mouseover, you can see the full text:

```
<div title="Hello I am a div element">Hello I am a div element</div>
```

Comment: That's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

create hidden inputs for every signle div and make input,and div have i unique id ,

in java script you can check value by equles div and input with same id .